# Not loading from the top

Tags: html, blogs

I have a blog and while loading it doesn't show the top. but when finished loading it shows from the top.

while loading: http://prntscr.com/1dv2x9

after: http://prntscr.com/1dv2zm

Somebody please help me... I tried to change margin-top and add some load scripts..but I can't figure out what I should change from the template source.

I tried to edit this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.jstiming) window.jstiming.load.tick('headEnd');
</script></head>
<body class='loading'>
<div class='navbar section' id='navbar'><div class='widget Navbar' id='Navbar1'><script type="text/javascript">
function setAttributeOnload(object, attribute, val) {
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener("load",
function(){ object[attribute] = val; }, false);
} else {
window.attachEvent('onload', function(){ object[attribute] = val;
 });
}
```

Comment: check for negative margins in the body or header structure, that could spot something useful, because answering that question this way is somewhat hard.

Comment: the only margin that is negative is the margin-top, because I set it like that cuz if it had the value '0' it would show like this: http://prntscr.com/1dvalr

Answer (score 0):

Converting previous comment as an answer:

check for negative margins in the body or header structure, that could spot something useful, because answering that question this way is somewhat hard.

Then:

If you are seeing a space on the top then probably you are not setting a margin:0  in the contained item, or padding:0 in your containing item.

Comment: can I give you the source so you can check it? skype: cosminagache

Comment: @NextLgZ: That's not how Stack Overflow works.  If you want somebody to debug and fix your code for you, consider hiring a developer.  If you have specific questions that we can answer to help *you* fix your code, those questions are welcome here.